# AJAX reload data with if conditions

Tags: php, html

I am working on a app with a drag and drop function that on drop, posts a set of variables to a handler to change the status of the item being dropped. I also have an AJAX script running to auto refresh the div with the updated database ID's.

The issue I have is that whilst the AJAX is reloading the div, I loose the ability to interact with the object. Is there a way to pause the AJAX whilst MouseDown is active or another way to handle this. I need the refresh of the Div to be every 100ms or so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your working code

Comment: JavaScript isn't preemptable, there's no way to interrupt code that's running. If you want to be able to do something like this, you'll need to break up your update code into multiple steps that run asychronously. Then if a mouse event occurs, it will be able to run between these async actions.

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you for this, I thought that would be the case but hoped it wouldnt be. I think I may split the app into elements that need to be live and those that don't. The live elements do not need to be moved or updated in the app. I don't suppose you have an example of a simple Async script do you?

Comment: @Barmar - Would something like this work: 

var flag = true;
function loop() {
    if (!flag) return;
    loopStep();
    setTimeout(loop, 0);
}

I would then define the var flag by the mousedown event?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make the loopStep function do very little work so it doesn't block the UI.